# Distributed session implementation detail

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, azure

With the reference to the structure of session module in ASP.NET below:

[image]

As I understand, when the application uses distributed session provider (.e.g. Redis in Azure), the SessionStateModule will deserializes the user's session data into Session dictionary at the beginning of a request.

What I'm wondering is whether the module will deserialize everything in user's session, or just session entry that accessed during that request? Let's say user's session has 3 entries A, B, C and only entry B is read in current request, will the module retrieve all 3 entries from distributed session, deserialize them into Session dictionary?

If it deserializes everything, the more data in user's session, the slower each request will become? since the more data will need to be retrieved/deserialized

Comment: Yes, and that's why when we moved to store our session in Redis we started to move the big items from Session and just cache them in Redis directly with the Redis client and adding them an expiration. Also pay attention that if you have very large items in your session it can also timeout when saving.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, session state assumes that provider deserializes/serializes whole state and hence more data is stored more time it takes to start/end request.

As an option if you need to store a lot of data - store infrequently needed pieces outside of session state and keep information on location of the data in the session state. Note that you'd need to figure security and expiration implications of such split state storage.

Alternatively if you are implementing your own provider you can implement your own [`SessionStateStoreData` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateStoreData_properties%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) with `Item` method that will dynamically query items as needed. Unfortunately there is no `async` version of the class and hence remote calls to get data will lead to unexpected delays in request processing code along with blocking threads from processing request.

More details can be found starting from [Implementing a Session-State Store Provider](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178587%28v=vs.140%29.aspx)